# Admobs identity verification failed using PAN card

Tags: admob, adsense

Admobs identity verification failed using Indian PAN card even though there is option for PAN card. I have uploaded my documents correctly as per requirement. But still it says Document uploaded is not supported type of document. Why? And how to fix this. I don't have any other document except PAN card.
Please help I have tried 3 times already but still failed.